# Getting positive feedback (10+ upvotes) after improving the answer

Tags: discussion, voting

Are there any answers which got downvoted, and after improving the quality of answer it got positive feedback (more than 10+ upvotes)?

I want to see the how they improve their answer so I can improve mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure for answers, but I am sure there were such reversals for questions.

Read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283809/993547) on Meta Stack Overflow for example. It talks about a hat during Winter Bash which was awarded when the question was turned around. According to [this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/06/so-long-winter-bash-2014/) one question was at -7 when the answer was posted. It is now at +82. That question actually didn't change much, so it really was the answer that did it.

Often such reversals on answers happen when the initial answer was just plain wrong due to the author misunderstanding the problem asked. This happens typically on low-quality questions. Then the answer is edited and the answer attracts quite some 'this seems okay' upvotes, which hardly reflect the overall quality of the posts.

When you are looking how to improve your posts, think of the user reading your answer. Does it help them just this time, because you just put in a single line code block which solves the issue but doesn't explain the *how* and *why*? Can you elaborate on your approach and what the actual reasoning behind your answer is? That is often more useful than comparing you to someone else's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of feel the premise of this question is incorrect. You don't actually want those downvotes. Don't be the fastest gun in the west shoot accurately and get the answer you should post in the first place.

There's no difference between a good unedited post, and one that has undergone bug fixes vs one that's written correctly to start it. On the other hand, a post that's well written to start with is a joy. Sure you can improve it later but really - you should be looking at what good answers are.

Look for good answers, borrow what you can as far as style and formatting goes (and add your own spin) and make sure you're posting the best answers you can.

These arn't always highly voted. They might not even be long - They might even be a single line and a screenshot done right. They do answer the question as completely and concisely as possible

Its the answers that educate and sometimes amuse. Its the ones that make the little +1 pop up over the head.  A good answer is a good answer and you can learn from them - edited or not, to post better answers to start with.

Being MSE, what a great answer is depends on where you are. Get that and you won't be fixing downvoted questions - you have lovely problems like repcapping.

Comment: Its not quite random. Its for emphasis. Seems that dosen't quite work here as well as it does elsewhere